# Why is defgroup useful?

Tags: customization

I'm reading the `ido` source and see:

```
(defgroup ido nil
 "Switch between files using substrings."
 :group 'extensions
 :group 'convenience
 :version "22.1"
 :link '(emacs-commentary-link :tag "Commentary" "ido.el")
 :link '(emacs-library-link :tag "Lisp File" "ido.el")
 :link '(custom-manual "(ido) Top")
 :link '(info-link "(ido) Customization"))
```

`defgroup` appears at the top of many large packages. I see it does this:

> Declare SYMBOL as a customization group containing MEMBERS.
>   SYMBOL does not need to be quoted.

And the [page on customization groups](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization-Groups.html) doesn't really answer when or how to use them. When or how do you use them?

Answer (score 10):

When and why do you use any grouping? To be able to act on the group as a whole or on its individual members - only its members.  That's the answer here also.

- There are commands and other functions that act on a given group or set of groups. `customize-group` is one that acts on a given group. `customize-apropos-groups` is one that acts on a set of groups.
- When you use `customize-group` you see links that let you customize subgroups (if any) and individual members (options and faces) of that group.

In addition, a group typically has a prefix, and you can use that for pattern-matching against function, face, etc. names when you interact with Emacs. This is another way of limiting actions to a given set (customization group) of things.

A group can also provide quick access to the online doc, source code, bug reporting, etc. for a package.  Here, for instance, is the definition of group `Icicles-Key-Completion` (with some code elided).

```
(defgroup Icicles-Key-Completion nil
  "Icicles preferences related to key completion (`icicle-complete-keys')."
  :prefix "icicle-" :group 'Icicles
  :link `(url-link :tag "Send Bug Report" ...)
  :link '(url-link :tag "Other Libraries by Drew" ...)
  :link '(url-link :tag "Download" ...)
  :link '(url-link :tag "Description" ...)
  :link '(emacs-commentary-link :tag "Doc-Part2" "icicles-doc2")
  :link '(emacs-commentary-link :tag "Doc-Part1" "icicles-doc1"))
```

This group is itself a subgroup of group `Icicles` (see `:group`).  It provides links in the Customize buffer for sending a bug report, downloading, and accessing the doc in the source code or on the Web.